# Why do client ids generated by Google for OAuth look like uris?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Client Ids generated when you create an OAuth application for Google APIs are generally in the form

```
xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

Is there any particular reasoning behind them being uris like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any particular reasoning behind them being uris like this?

First off they dont look like URLs at least not to me just because a string ends in .com and contains .'s does not really mean that its a URL.

### what is a client id?

A client id is just a string identifier for a client in an authorization server. The company that runs the authorization server generates their own client ids.  The only real requirement is that a client id must be unique across all clients as its well a unique identifier for the client application.

## googles client id

As to why google chose that format i dont think anyone here can really answer that 100% but i could guess that well.

xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com

- apps - its an app
- googleuserconsent - it is used for granting user consent as its not an api key.

## What i have done

In my experience with previous authorization severs that i have run i normally do

> {GUILD}.companyurl

but again this is up to the person in charge of the authorization server that uses the clients.

In one instance we had a production and a test server so i did something like

> {GUILD}.test.companyurl

This was to help developers testing on the test system to be able to keep track of if it was a test or a production client.

## Differentiate between clients across servers

The reason i use a URL in the end of the client id (and may be why google does as well) is so that developers can tell the difference between client ids for different companies authorization servers. if Google, twitter and Facebook all just used GUID you would never know where the client id came from.

Comment: Thanks. That helps, and makes sense